# Android Spinner : Retrieving values from JSON array and displaying it in a spinner one after the other

Tags: android, json, spinner

I have a problem of using json to retrieve the value and fetch in to the spinner selecting the time

`JSON`:

```
{
   "offer_detail":[
      {
         "movieid":"72",
         "date_value":"2014-05-11",
         "showtime":[
            "10:30 AM",
            "2:30 PM",
            "6:30 PM",
            "9:30 PM"
         ],
         "screen_no":"SCREEN 2",
         "id":"186"
      }
   ],
   "success":1,
   "message":"Successfully found "
}
```

I'm trying to display the showtime inside a spinner with respective times 
for ex - 10:30AM
         2:30pm 
         6:30PM
         9:30PM

but in my case, it displays the whole `showtime` array instead of displaying the times separately.

And this is what i've tried:

```
c = JSONfunctions
        .getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.1.104/OnlineTicketBooking/book_now1.php?movieid='72'");
try {

JSONArray jarray = c.getJSONArray("offer_detail");
ArrayList<String> xyz= new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
 c = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
xyz.add(c.getString("showtime"));
Log.d("get value",c.getString("showtime"));


}
```

.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Booking.this,      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,xyz);
dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spin.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
String cl=spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
String filenameArray[] = cl.split(",");

int size =  filenameArray.length;
Log.d("count",""+size);
ArrayList<String> nw = new ArrayList<String>(); 

for (int j = 0; j < filenameArray.length; j++) {  
    JSONObject c = jarray.getJSONObject(j);
    nw.add(c.getString("showtime"));
     Log.d("getvalue",c.getString("showtime"));

}
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Booking.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,nw);
dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spin.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), spin.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String cl=spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Log.d("classname",cl);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
c = JSONfunctions
    .getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.1.104/OnlineTicketBooking/book_now1.php?movieid='72'");
try {

   JSONArray jarray = c.getJSONArray("offer_detail");
   ArrayList<String> xyz= new ArrayList<String>();
   for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
   JSONArray timeArray = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("showtime");
   for(int j = 0; j < timeArray .length(); j++){
   xyz.add(timeArray .getString(j));
 Log.d("get value",timeArray .getString(j));
  } 
 }
```

Try the above code

Comment: Please vote the answer so that others will also follow this code

Answer (score 2):

Try it....

```
c = JSONfunctions
    .getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.1.104/OnlineTicketBooking/book_now1.php?movieid='72'");
try {

   JSONArray jarray = c.getJSONArray("offer_detail");
   ArrayList<String> xyz= new ArrayList<String>();
   for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
   JSONArray timeArray = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("showtime");
   for(int j = 0; j < timeArray .length(); j++){
   xyz.add(timeArray .getString(j));
 Log.d("get value",timeArray .getString(i));
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Nice, but dude it is displaying the first value four times and not the other values.

Comment: ohh..
Please change xyz.add(timeArray .getString(i));
to
xyz.add(timeArray .getString(j));